# Getting "BadRequest" when posting data to SharePoint Online list with HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, sharepoint-online

I am trying to post data to a list on SharePoint Online with the C# HttpClient. this is my code:

```
  using (var client = new SPHttpClient(webUri, userName, password))
        {
            var listTitle = "HttpClientList";
            var itemPayload = new
            {
                __metadata = new
                {
                    type = "SP.Data.HttpClientListListItem"
                },
                Title = "test3",<--column name "Title"
                _x0071_cr5 = "value3"<--column name "Value"
            };
            var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{1}')/items", webUri, listTitle);
            var data = client.ExecuteJson(endpointUrl, HttpMethod.Post, itemPayload);
            Console.WriteLine("Task item '{0}' has been created", data["d"]["Title"]);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

As of right now, I am getting status "400, BadRequest". My guess is that I am missing something or feeding the post request the wrong data.
I have been following this blogpost [Blogpost](https://blog.vgrem.com/2015/04/04/consume-sharepoint-online-rest-service-using-net/)
I can only execute the verb GET. All other verbs gives me "400, BadRequest"

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if there is more details in the body of the response.

Comment: I have some developments: I can now create and update data, but only for the Title column, Cant create or update more then one column. I can still not delete items.  cant find the body of the response. can only find: "RequestMessage","StatusCode", "Headers", "EnsureSuccessStatusCode", "IsSuccessStatusCode" Perhapse i am looking at ther wrong place for the body

Comment: you get the body out of the response content.`body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: The delete problem was mentioned in the blogpost it's comments

Comment: Yes! You are so right. Delete working. only post and put to multipl columns left

Comment: canty get the body out the way you showed me

Comment: Well, does `TaskListItem` have a property Value, or is your list of a custom type? Is the list type you are sending this item to also a TaskList?

Comment: changed the `TaskListItem`  to  `HttpClientListListItem` wich has two columns. Realised that Tasks was from the demo

Comment: but still cnat post or put more then one column

Comment: for the love of good, Everything works now I can post and Put to multipl columns. The Values column was created using the quick create tool in the ListView. When I created a new column thru the ListSettings panel it started working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with varoius solutions.

Added the right ListItem `HttpClientListListItem`.
created all columns thru the ListSettings panel.
Replaced the `client.ExecuteJson()` with `client.ExecuteJson(endpointUrl, HttpMethod.Post, headers, default(string));`.
 Thanks for all the help!